# Why do I end up with my param names instead of their values in this PDO insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is actually my first project where I use PDO.

It worked very well so far but in this particular case I end up with the following content in my database:

[image]

The unmodified code I use is this:

```
<?php
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=domain-me;port=3306','domain-me','****',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));
$sql="
INSERT INTO  payments_paypal (
tid ,
txn_id ,
item_number ,
item_name ,
mc_currency ,
mc_gross ,
payment_date ,
payment_status ,
custom ,
payer_email ,
raw_data
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  ':txn_id',  ':item_number',  ':item_name',  ':mc_currency',  ':mc_gross',  ':payment_date',  ':payment_status',  ':custom',  ':payer_email',  ':raw_data'
);
";
$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$do=$sth->execute(array(':txn_id'=>@$_POST["txn_id"],':item_number'=>$_POST["item_number"],':item_name'=>$_POST["item_name"],':mc_currency'=>$_POST["mc_currency"],':mc_gross'=>$_POST["mc_gross"],':payment_date'=>$_POST["payment_date"],':payment_status'=>$_POST["payment_status"],':custom'=>$_POST["custom"],':payer_email'=>$_POST["payer_email"],':raw_data'=>$_POST["raw_data"],));
?>
```

edit:

I now did it using the old mysql_function and it works now. However I have this query that works just fine:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( puid,refcode,extuid, login,login_proxy, pass, email) 
VALUES (:puid,:refcode,:extuid,:login,:login_proxy,:pass,:email);";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        $do = $sth->execute(
                array(
                ':puid' => $refuser,
                ':refcode' => crc32(uniqid('')),
                ':extuid' => md5(uniqid('')),
                ':login' => $_POST['login'],
                ':login_proxy' => $_POST['login'],
                ':pass' => sha1($_POST['pass']),
                ':email' => $_POST['email'] ,
                )
        );
```

Comment: have you tried without the single quotes in your insert statement?

Comment: yes, then it dont works at all. currently debugging that.

Comment: don't use the error suppression operator (@) if you're trying to see errors hehe

Comment: the point is that i dont call the page myself. its called by paypal servers, i need to mail them to me. to not break the script executions the @operator makes sense here.

Comment: i did it using the old mysql_connect function snow, it works now. its weird anyway

Comment: @Joe: Don't supress errors/warnings anyways. Do something like `$txn_id = (isset($_POST['txn_id']) ? $_POST['txn_id'] : ''` and use `$txn_id` in your query instead. Tedious, but doesn't paper over errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when doing an INSERT or UPDATE you need to specify the names in the insert values array without the colons. Try this:

```
<?php
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=domain-me;port=3306','domain-me','****',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));
$sql="
INSERT INTO  payments_paypal (
tid ,
txn_id ,
item_number ,
item_name ,
mc_currency ,
mc_gross ,
payment_date ,
payment_status ,
custom ,
payer_email ,
raw_data
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  ':txn_id',  ':item_number',  ':item_name',  ':mc_currency',  ':mc_gross',  ':payment_date',  ':payment_status',  ':custom',  ':payer_email',  ':raw_data'
);
";
$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$do=$sth->execute(array('txn_id'=>@$_POST["txn_id"],'item_number'=>$_POST["item_number"],'item_name'=>$_POST["item_name"],'mc_currency'=>$_POST["mc_currency"],'mc_gross'=>$_POST["mc_gross"],'payment_date'=>$_POST["payment_date"],'payment_status'=>$_POST["payment_status"],'custom'=>$_POST["custom"],'payer_email'=>$_POST["payer_email"],'raw_data'=>$_POST["raw_data"],));
?>
```

Comment: sounds sound but i cannot confirm that. i have another query with colons, and it works just fine. i added it to the answer as a comment. however +1